# when site loads make a call to another in background, but user remains on same page

Tags: javascript, html

I have plain html site.

I was wondering if is possible to make a call to another link when site loads but user stays on same page and it doesnt open in a new tab. It just records a visits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try: `<iframe src="https://www.another-link.com/" style="display:none"></iframe>`

Comment: This works, I was wondering if is possible to make a call to <iframe> with dispay none, after some time ? for example after 2 sec ?

Comment: @Marko I didn't catch your question. Do you want to add dislpay:none after 2 sec?

Comment: solved that. Can iframe be placed in href element for ex <a href ='<iframe src="https://www.another-link.com/" style="display:none"></iframe>' /> when user clicks it will open new page but remain on same

Comment: @Marko No, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambious but you can try this: 
**If the page is on your site:**

```js
x = new XMLHTTPRequest;
x.open("GET", "/your-link/filename.html");
x.send();
```

*Note:* The link `/your-link/filename.html` must be on your server, for that to work because it avoids Cross request forgery stuff.